# APEX hightlight row according to column comparison

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I have a report in APEX which shows a JOIN of two tables. Both tables have a value for, for example, telephone number. If the two telephone numbers do not match I want the row to be highlihgted.

I looked at the highlighting options in Actions>Format>Highlight but it seems I can only compare a column value to a particular value and not another column.

I'm very new to APEX so I might be missing something obvious! I've read other questions and answers but they seem to be dealing with more complex things. They spoke about making an invisible column and changing the value of that but I'm not sure how I would do that.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: As I mentioned inn the second paragraph I don't know how to compare 2 rows, only 1 row to a set value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a pseudo column in your query to flag records of interest. Then compare to the flag:

```
SELECT a.phone, b.phone
      ,CASE WHEN a.phone = b.phone THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS match
  FROM a, b
  WHERE a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't compare another column per row in the ir highlighting. So either output html through your query for the column you want formatted, or use javascript/dynamic actions.

Sql:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN a.phone = b.phone THEN htf.escape_sc(a.phone) 
            ELSE '<div class="highlight">'||htf.escape_sc(a.phone)||'</div>'
       END AS phone_highlight
FROM a, b
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

(escaping special characters when you output html!)
Plus, set the column to be displayed as 'standard report column', so it'll render the html and not escape it.

Personally, i'd go for javascript:
Dynamic action, After refresh, execute javascript, check "fire on page load":

```
$("td[headers='TELEPHONE1']").each(function(){
   var lTest = $(this).siblings("[headers='TELEPHONE2']").text();
   if($(this).text()!= lTest){
      $(this).addClass("highlight");
   };
});
```

This will add the highlight class to the cells for telephone1 which differ from telephone2 in the same row.

In both cases i worked with a class, so you'll have to provide that as well. (sure, you could use .css() in js, but i like styling to be seperated from functionality) 
Eg style tags in head:

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight{
   background-color: yellow;
   color: purple;
}
</style>
```

This allows for non-polluted sql, javascript without styling , and styles in css.

Comment: Thank you for your excellent post, it will certainly be of use to me in the future. However for the time being Glenn's answer is the most simple for my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this solution from the search and first of all thank you for the time you put into this ansewr.  I follwed you all the way up to:

"In both cases i worked with a class, so you'll have to provide that as well. (sure, you could use .css() in js, but i like styling to be seperated from functionality) Eg style tags in head:

```
<style type="text/css">
.highlight{
 background-color: yellow;
 color: purple;
 }
 </style>"
```

Where would you "provide" this in Apex?  Thanks again,